# How to remove the specific characters using regex

Tags: c#, regex

How will i solve this? please don't mind the text of data annotation, this is for testing only. How will i remove the data annotation?

```
   [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters",
        MessageId = "YouSource.DI.Web.Areas.HelpPage.TextSample.#ctor(System.String)",
        Justification = "End users may choose to merge this string with existing localized resources.")]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA2204:Literals should be spelled correctly",
        MessageId = "bsonspec",
        Justification = "Part of a URI.")]
    public int Get1Number([FromBody]string name)
```

I have this code

```
    public void RemovePublicModifier()
    {
        this.method = this.SanitizeString(this.method, Public);
    }
    public void RemoveDataAnnotation()
    {
        int startIndex = this.method.LastIndexOf(']');
        var result = this.method.Substring(startIndex + 1).Trim();

        this.method = result;
    }
    private string SanitizeString(string method, string filter)
    {
        var items = method.Split(' ').ToList();
        var publicItem = items.Where(i => i == filter).FirstOrDefault();
        if (publicItem != null)
        {
            items.Remove(publicItem);
        }
        var result = string.Join(" ", items.ToArray()).Trim();
        return result;
    }
```

but it gives me a wrong result.

```
       string name)
```

What i want is.

```
      int Get1Number([FromBody]string name)
```

Comment: Is the word of `public` you also want to remove?

Comment: yes, i want to remove also the word public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string inputStr = @"[SuppressMessage(""Microsoft.Globalization"", ""CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters"",
MessageId = ""YouSource.DI.Web.Areas.HelpPage.TextSample.#ctor(System.String)"",
Justification = ""End users may choose to merge this string with existing localized resources."")]
[SuppressMessage(""Microsoft.Naming"", ""CA2204:Literals should be spelled correctly"",
MessageId = ""bsonspec"",
Justification = ""Part of a URI."")]
public int Get1Number([FromBody]string name)";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"(^|\s*)\[[\s\S]*?\]\s*public\s+", string.Empty));

public is also removed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try performing this regex replacement:

```
(?ims)^\s*\[(?!\bpublic\b)[\s\S]*?\)\]\s*public\s*
```

Replace with an empty string.

C#:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?ims)^\s*\[(?!\bpublic\b)[\s\S]*?\)\]\s*public\s*", string.Empty);
```

Here is a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fims)%5e%5cs*%5c%5b(%3f!%5cbpublic%5cb)%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f%5c)%5c%5d%5cs*public%5cs*&i=+%5bSuppressMessage(%22Microsoft.Globalization%22%2c+%22CA1303%3aDo+not+pass+literals+as+localized+parameters%22%2c%0d%0a++++++++MessageId+%3d+%22YouSource.DI.Web.Areas.HelpPage.TextSample.%23ctor(System.String)%22%2c%0d%0a++++++++Justification+%3d+%22End+users+may+choose+to+merge+this+string+with+existing+localized+resources.%22)%5d%0d%0a++++%5bSuppressMessage(%22Microsoft.Naming%22%2c+%22CA2204%3aLiterals+should+be+spelled+correctly%22%2c%0d%0a++++++++MessageId+%3d+%22bsonspec%22%2c%0d%0a++++++++Justification+%3d+%22Part+of+a+URI.%22)%5d%0d%0a++++public+int+Get1Number(%5bFromBody%5dstring+name)%0d%0a+%5bSuppressMessage(%22Microsoft.Globalization%22%2c+%22CA1303%3aDo+not+pass+literals+as+localized+parameters%22%2c%0d%0a++++++++MessageId+%3d+%22YouSource.DI.Web.Areas.HelpPage.TextSample.%23ctor(System.String)%22%2c%0d%0a++++++++Justification+%3d+%22End+users+may+choose+to+merge+this+string+with+existing+localized+resources.%22)%5d%0d%0a++++%5bSuppressMessage(%22Microsoft.Naming%22%2c+%22CA2204%3aLiterals+should+be+spelled+correctly%22%2c%0d%0a++++++++MessageId+%3d+%22bsonspec%22%2c%0d%0a++++++++Justification+%3d+%22Part+of+a+URI.%22)%5d%0d%0a++++public+int+Get1Number(%5bFromBody%5dstring+name))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"(?<!\()\[[^\]]+\]\r\n", string.Empty));
```

It matches a text enclosed in `[]` but not where they are preceded by a `(`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex, it will eliminate the suppress messages and also support for other access modifiers too:

```
(\[[^]]+\)\])(?<modifiers>\s+\w+\s)?
```

If you don't want to remove access modifiers then simply skip this named group during `Regex.Replace`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ9aR3/2)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will extract the `int Get1Number([FromBody]string name)` to the `text` variable.

```
var input = @" [SuppressMessage(""Microsoft.Globalization"", ""CA1303: Do not pass literals as localized parameters"",
        MessageId = ""YouSource.DI.Web.Areas.HelpPage.TextSample.#ctor(System.String)"",
        Justification = ""End users may choose to merge this string with existing localized resources."")]
    [SuppressMessage(""Microsoft.Naming"", ""CA2204:Literals should be spelled correctly"",
        MessageId = ""bsonspec"",
        Justification = ""Part of a URI."")]
        public int Get1Number([FromBody]string name)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\w+\s+\w+\(\[FromBody\]\w+\s+\w+\)");
var text = match.Groups[0].Value;
```